# How to reload instance variables after an ajax call in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, datatables, instance-variables

I work on a project with Ruby on rails. I currently have some issues with my index page on which I use Datatables to display my data.
I use the server-side option to display my data since it's a very large database. I added a selector to allow the user to select a project whose vulnerabilities he wants to see. I managed to get the project in my controller and I passed it in an instance variable because I need it in my view. However, the variable isn't reloaded with the ajax call.
How can I reload the instance variables in my view ? I don't need only the project but also other variables such as the displayed variables to make graphs depending on the criticity...
Maybe I'm doing this the wrong way. Could you help me ? Below is my code.

View :

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-xs-8" style="display: inline-block">
  <div class="x_panel">
    <h4>Filtres</h4>
    <div class="x_content">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6" style="display: inline-block">
        <label>Filter by projet : </label>
        <%= select_tag "datatable_project", options_from_collection_for_select(@user.projects, :id, :name), include_blank: "Tous", onchange: "selectProject(this.value)" %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="x_panel">
  <table id="datatable-history-external" class="table responsive-utilities mcs-datatable-history-external" width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr class="headings">
        <th class="column-title all" style="width:150px">CVE</th>
        <th class="column-title all">Base score</th>
        <% if not @selected_project.nil? and @selected_project.level == 2 %>
          <th class="column-title all">Environmental score</th>
        <% else %>
          <th class="column-title never"></th>
        <% end %>
        <th class="column-title none">Description</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```

I want to display an new column if the level of the selected project is 2. I tried to change the class from the javascript but it didn't work since I use responsive to display a childRow.

Controller :

```
def pagination
  # Recuperation of the DataTable parameters
  draw = params[:draw]
  longueur = params[:length]
  start = params[:start]

  # Call method from model to get validated vulnerabilities
  vulnerability_ids = []
  #get project selection from the user
  selected_project_id = get_selection
  if not selected_project_id.blank?
    @selected_project = Project.find(selected_project_id)
    vulnerability_ids = @selected_project.validated_vulnerabilities.pluck(:id)
  else
    @user.projects.each {|project| vulnerability_ids += project.validated_vulnerabilities.pluck(:id)}
  end
  vulnerability_ids = vulnerability_ids.uniq
  @vulnerabilities = Vulnerability.where(id: vulnerability_ids)

  result = []

  result = @vulnerabilities.offset(start.to_i).limit(longueur.to_i)
  recordsTotal = @vulnerabilities.length

  # creation of the json that we want to return and display
  result_json = create_datatable_json(result, draw, recordsTotal)

  render :json =>result_json.to_json
 end
```

Controller Helper :

```
def get_selections
  parameters = request.query_parameters
  selected_project = parameters["project"]

  return selected_project
end

def create_datatable_json(result, draw, recordsTotal)
  vulns = []
  result.each do |vul|
    cves = []

    #if there is a selected project and it is of level 2 we want to display a column with the max environmental notation
    if @selected_project.nil? or not @selected_project.analysis_level == 2
      max_environmental_score = "NC"
    else
      max_environmental_notation = EnvironmentalNotation.get_max_environmental_notation(vul, @selected_project).environmental_score
    end

    if vul.notation
      vuln = [:id => vul.id, :cve => first_cves, :base_score => vul.notation.base_score.to_s, :description => vul.description, :environmental_score => max_environmental_score.to_s]
    else
      vuln = [:id => vul.id, :cve => first_cves, :base_score => "NC", :description => vul.description, :environmental_score => max_environmental_score.to_s]
    end

    vulns += vuln
  end
  result_json = {
    :draw => draw,
    :recordsTotal => recordsTotal,
    :recordsFiltered => recordsTotal,
    :data => vulns
  }
  return result_json

end
```

Javascript :

```
// Select project to filter the vulnerabilities to display in table
function selectProject(value) {
    project = value;
    Turbolinks.visit(window.location); 
}

$(document).on("turbolinks:load", function() {
    $('.mcs-datatable-history-external').each(function() {
        if ($.fn.dataTable.isDataTable($(this))){
            $(this).destroy();
        }
        var url = "vulnerabilities/pagination;
        if (project != null) {
            url = url+"/?project="+project;
            $('#datatable_project').val(project);
        }

        add_in_array(
            $(this).DataTable({
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                stateSave: true,
                responsive: {
                details: {
                    display: $.fn.dataTable.Responsive.display.childRowImmediate,
                    type: '',
                    target: 3
                }
            },
            ajax: {
                type: "POST",
                format: "js",
                url: url
            },
            columns: [
                { data: "cve", targets:0},
                {  data: "base_score", targets:1, orderable: true, searchable: true},
                {  data: "environmental_score", targets:2, orderable: true, searchable: false},        
                {  data: "description", className: "no-border-top", targets:3, orderable: false, searchable: true},
            ],
            searching: true,
        }));
    })
}
```

I need to get @selected_project and @vulnerabilities in my view but they are nil.

I don't know if I'm clear enough. I've put a lot of code here. Don't hesitate to ask for some explanations if needed.

Comment: I think the problem comes from my use of turbolinks : the whole page isn't reloaded. I tried setting a route during project selection to reload the entire page but it doesn't seem to work either. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3):

first make sure that the changes are saved to data base later if the instance is not reloaded then you can use

```
@instance_variable.reload
```

To reload the instance

You can use it whenever you need to display/use the updated data of instance. Say there is an instance `@user` and you have updated the details of user like `@user.email`  in the db and later you need to display the email of user using that instance like `@user.email`. In such case the instance doesnt get reloaded and it will display the previous value.

So if you use `@user.reload` then rails will fetch the details of that instance from DB. so that there will be less scope for error

Comment: Where should I use that ? Can you explain how it would work ?

Comment: @kapoue updated my answer with some info fell free to ask if any doubts

Comment: Thanks but that's not what I need. In the controller I get the right instance of my variable. It just doesn't seem to make it to the view (nil only in the view).

Comment: try adding the following line where you get nil values   <%@instance.reload!%>

Comment: why are you declaring the instance variable selected_project as nil???there is no need to do that you can directly write @selected_project = Project.find(selected_project_id)

Comment: I tried adding <%@instance.reload!%> where I get nil values but I get the error undefined method `reload!' for nil:NilClass.

Comment: Maybe it's not useful to first declare the variable as nil but it's not the issue. The same thing happen when I remove this line.